# JSP Session Working Only On One Page

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I have a problem. After user log in he get redirected to index.jsp:

```
if(loggedIn){
    request.setAttribute("login", signum);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

Everything is working like a charm index.jsp is displayed in the top right corner of the screen I have a small menu with log out bottom and username link. When user clicks on that link he is redirected to the profile page.

Problem is that when he clicks on that link he is redirected there but beside log out button is nothing like a session got missing.
Here is a code for session and small menu:

```
<li>
            <% session.setAttribute( "username", request.getAttribute("login") ); %>
                <a id='loginLink' href='/logout.jsp' onclick='return logout();'>Logout</a> <span id='user'><a href='userProfile.jsp'>${login}</a></span>
            </li>
```

Note that instead of `${login}` I used `session.getAttribute("username"))` but there was the same problem. This menu is included on every page with: `<jsp:include page="menu.jsp" />`
Please tell me what I am doing wrong I thought that if the menu is included in all pages session should be stored and shared across all pages?

Comment: In what servlet is the code `if(loggedIn){
    request.setAttribute("login", signum);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }` and in what servlet is the code `<% session.setAttribute( "username", request.getAttribute("login") ); %>` ?

Comment: `if (<% session.setAttribute( "username", request.getAttribute("login") ); %>)` is not a servlet it is just a jsp page (menu.jsp) which is included in all pages.
`if(loggedIn){     request.setAttribute("login", signum);     request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);     }` and that code is in loginServlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write userid in session in login servlet and not in menu. If not, you will erase the session `username` attribute with the `login` attribute of the request ... which is only present in the login page !

You should do in your loginServlet :

```
if(loggedIn){
    // eventually : HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("username", signum);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

and then in your menu :

```
<li>
    <a id='loginLink' href='/logout.jsp' onclick='return logout();'>Logout</a> <span id='user'><a href='userProfile.jsp'>${username}</a></span>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I was mistaken thinking that session will be persistent if the menu is included on all pages. That works perfectly thanks a lot :)